# Microsoft Graph API: 'Delegated' or 'Application' permissions for cron app

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm building a marketing automation tool that uses the Microsoft Graph API to send automated emails on behalf of our users (our users are external people, not part of our Azure org).

Essentially, a user signs up using the **Sign up and sign in** user flow provided by **Azure AD B2C**. Then we're using a cron job to trigger a function on our server every minute. This function loops through all of our user's email sequences, and when an email is ready to be sent, sends an email on a user's behalf.

Should I be using Microsoft's **delegated** api permissions or **application** api permissions (I think Microsoft call this a Daemon app) for this use case? My intuition tells me delegated, but in that case our app would have to create a different Microsoft Graph Client for each user we need to send an email on behalf of, like so:

```
sequences.forEach(sequence => {
  // We could have thousands of sequences, and therefore thousands of msGraphClients
  const msGraphClient = Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) =>
      done(
        null,
        sequence.user.accessToken
      ),
  });

  sequence.contacts.forEach(sequenceContact => {
    // Send an email to a sequence contact on the user's behalf using the msGraphClient
  })
})
```

Is this the right way to do it, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is as following:

Delegated permissions assume you have an authenticated user sitting in front of the PC (a user that can log in, in case the authorization/refresh token expires for example, confirming his login with MFA using his phone if needed). The things the app can do on user behalf is limited to what the app has requested, and what the user has consented to when approving the app ("scopes").

Application permission assumes that your application has its own identity and permissions, so the emails it sends will be sent from that application, and not on the user behalf. The things the app can do are again limited to what scopes it has requested/were approved by the administrator when approving the app. Note that application-level permissions require administrator approval, a normal user cannot do that.

I am not convinced that the scenario where a daemon app sends emails on behalf of users using Microsoft graph is feasible at all, as this looks like a security concern to me...

Comment: Hi Nikolay, isn't the purpose of the offline_access scope to allow an app to act on a users behalf when they are not currently logged in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access Also, when you say "the emails it sends will be sent from that application, and not on the user behalf" what email address would the emails actually be sent from?

Comment: As far as I know, the offline_access allows application to work *longer* than standard access_token, but not infinitely longer. At some point, the user will be asked to log in, anyway. But you are right, you can actually grant application the rights to send email as any user (not only itself), then you send it just like "/users/<userid>/sendMail".

Comment: So, it looks like I was wrong, and application permission will be good to send email as any user. You just use a bit different API.

Comment: Nikolay, very interesting! Would this api ("/users/<userid>/sendMail") work for external users not inside our org? If yes, how does our Azure app know who it has permissions to send email on behalf of? I'm guessing it stores this information when an external user signs up and grants scope permissions (e.g. mail.send)? Finally, could you possibly link to an example/docs of how to set all of this up (even better if the example uses 'next-auth' for authentication)?

Comment: It looks like in this case you don't need to impoersonate user, the application will just send an email using that user's as a sender

Comment: Hi Nikolay, could you provide any docs stating that application permissions allow us to send mail on behalf of users outside your Azure org? I ask because I'm getting conflicting information from a 'Microsoft Community Expert' on this question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1032296/delegated-or-application-permissions-for-cron-app.html He says "if you are building an application that is aimed at the public, not your organization, then daemons will not apply because daemons can only send mail on behalf of users within your organization."

Comment: I am not sure, how wide the application permissions could expand, and if they apply only within your organization. If the microsoft expert is saying it cannot expand beyond your organization, that is most probably the case. I have not tried that myself; I have only experience with delegated permissions for externals and application permissions within my organization. As far as I understand this means the daemon app can't act on behalf of users outside of your organization, right?

Comment: Another thing, B2C has probably nothing to do with all that, like you were also told on that linked thread.